# how to Insert data in session using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

need help.

```
$ses_data = array('session_un'  => $_POST['username'],'session_pd'  =>   $_POST['password'],'session_id'  => 1,'logged_in' => TRUE);

$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Result:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: session_data
>
> Filename: controllers/task.php
>
> Line Number: 110

Comment: $ses_data, or $session_data?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your are using `$ses_data` as variable and then you switch to `$session_data`, change as follow

```
$ses_data = array('session_un'  => $_POST['username'],'session_pd'  =>   $_POST['password'],'session_id'  => 1,'logged_in' => TRUE);

$this->session->set_userdata($ses_data);
                           //^ use here $ses_data instead of $session_data 
                           //  which is not defined
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: still facing error below in link 111 (print_r($_SESSION))
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: _SESSION

Filename: controllers/task.php

Line Number: 111

Comment: @WaqasAhmed did you start the session?

Comment: Codeigniter session doesn't use native php session... in answer above, you can see how to set and get ci sessions...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Codeigniter:

```
$ses_data = array('session_un'  => $this->input->post('username'),
'session_pd'  =>   $this->input->post('password'),'session_id'  => 1,
'logged_in' => TRUE);

$this->session->set_userdata($ses_data);

print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are still facing $_SESSION undefined because CodeIgniter, as said in documentation:

> ...does not utilize native PHP sessions. It generates its own session
>   data, offering more flexibility for developers.

So there is no $_SESSION available, because you didn't set session_start() at top of every page.

Have in mind, $_SESSION is PHP native.

$CI->session is an object from CI's class, and has nothing to do with $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

`$session_data` should be `$ses_data`.

`$session_data` was not defined when you called that method.